# Python: replacing multiple list items by one

Tags: python

I want to write a calculator program. My goal is to replace multiple list items(with datatype `str`) by one(`int`). I've tried the `.insert()` method, but it creates a new inner list and places it at the end of the main list.

*Something like this:*

```py
input_list = ['4','5','6','+','8','7','4']

#expected result
output_list = [456, '+', 874]

#actual result
input_list = ['4','5','6','+','8','7','4',['4','5','6']]
```

I also tried extend method and also without success.

**My code:**

```py
num = ""
start = ""
for x in range(len(list)):
    if list[x].isdigit() == True:
        if start == "":
            start = x    
            num += list[x]
            continue
        else:
            num += list[x]
            continue     
    else:
        num = int(num)
        list.insert(num,list[start:x])
        num = ""
        start = ""
        continue
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and pass `str.isdigit` to its key. It will group the numbers together.

```py
from itertools import groupby

input_list = ["4", "5", "6", "+", "8", "7", "4"]

result = []
for k, g in groupby(input_list, key=str.isdigit):
    string = "".join(g)
    # It's True for numbers, False for operators.
    if k:
        number = int(string)
        result.append(number)
    else:
        result.append(string)

print(result)
```

output:

```
[456, '+', 874]
```

It's also possible with list-comprehension:

```py
from itertools import groupby

input_list = ["4", "5", "6", "+", "8", "7", "4"]

result = [
    int("".join(g)) if k else "".join(g)
    for k, g in groupby(input_list, key=str.isdigit)
]

print(result)
```

---

***Note:*** I intentionally wrote two `"".join(g)` inside the list-comprehension. Because I had to. Don't try using walrus because you won't get your expected result:

```py
result = [
    int((s := "".join(g))) if k else s
    for k, g in groupby(input_list, key=str.isdigit)
]
```

the `(s := "".join(g))` part is only evaluated when the `k` is `True`, not always. That means if `k` is `False`, you'll get the previous value of `s` which is evaluated in the previous iteration which is `'456'`.

Comment: What about float numbers?

Comment: change `int` to `float` and change `key=str.isdigit` to `key=lambda l: l.isdigit or l == '.'`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `list.insert(num,list[start:x])`. You are inserting the result into your input list, `list` itself. You should create an empty list and insert the results in it. I also suggest using `output_list.append(num)` instead, when adding `num` to your output list.

Answer (score 1):

I woudn't recommend replacing values in the `input_list` as list manipulation is one of the most hard and finicky things you can do.
Also **never** name a list `list`, because `list` normally means the `list` type. (you can see that by the syntax highlighting).
If you use an output list, then the `start` variable becomes redundant
Here is the fixed code:

```py
input_list = ['4','5','6','+','8','7','4']
output_list = []
num = ""
for x in range(len(input_list)):
    if input_list[x].isdigit() == True: # check if char x is a digit
        num += input_list[x] # add to num
    elif num == "": # num is empty so add the char directly to output_list
        output_list.append(input_list[x])
    else: # add num to output_list
        output_list.append(int(num))
        num = ""
        output_list.append(input_list[x]) # add the current char (which wasn't a digit back to the output_list)
if num != "": # add the last number
    output_list.append(int(num))
print(output_list)
> [456, '+', 874]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
endChars = "/*+- "
output = []
temp = ""

for char in input_list:

        if char not in endChars:

            temp += char

        else:

            if temp != " ":
            
                output.append(temp)
 
            if char != " "

                output.append(char)

            temp = ""

output.append(temp)

print(output)
```